# Even though I inserted 20 (distinct) elements into my std::set, it only has a size of 14?

Tags: c++, stl

```
typedef vector<int> vec;

struct classcomp {
    bool operator() (const vec& vec1, const vec& vec2) const{
        if (vec1[0] > vec2[0]){
            return true;
        }
    
        return false;
    }            
};

int main() {
    set<vec, classcomp> v; 

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        v.insert({rand() % 20, i});
    }

    cout << "size: " << v.size() << endl;

    for (auto e : v) {
        cout << e[0] << " " << e[1] << endl;
    }
}
```

In the above C++ code, I have defined a custom comparator and a ordered set of vectors which is sorted based on the first entry of the vector. I understand that the set does not store duplicates, but I inserted 20 distinct vectors (the second entry is unique for each vector), yet my set only has a size of 14. Why is this?

Comment: The vectors are _not_ distinct within the definition of your `classcomp` comparator.

Comment: Why are you using vectors that each only contain a single number?

Comment: What underlying problem is this set of vectors supposed to solve? Why have you made up the ordering function the way you have?

Comment: Also please note that a type-alias like `typedef vector<int> vec;` doesn't make the code easier to read and understand, quite the opposite. If you really need a type-alias, then please give it a semantically relevant name.

Comment: Whole lot of duping going on: https://godbolt.org/z/rWjxc7rnW

Comment: *but I inserted 20 distinct vectors* -- The code from @user4581301 produces a size of `12` when run under Visual C++.

Comment: Try saving the result of `rand()%20` in a temporary value that you can print. I'll bet you get a few duplicates.

Comment: This code does not insert 20 distinct elements into a set.  It inserts between 1 to 20 distinct elements into a set, and others are not distinct elements and are not inserted.

Comment: Minor point: that comparison is usually written `return vec1[0] > vec2[0];`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::set` does not use `operator ==` to distinguish duplicate values. Instead, it uses `Compare` template argument to both order elements and tell when they are *equivalent*. The formal requirements for this argument can be found here: [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare), but the important one is this one:

if `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`
then `a` and `b` are considered equivalent and `insert` operation fails.

Since your comparator only checks for value of first element of the vector, then any `insert` that tries to add another vector with identical first element will fail.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Linking to [Compare](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) documentation for specification on requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Because your custom comparator only compares the first element in the vector; it doesn't care about the second one...

```
if (vec1[0] > vec2[0]){
   return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: The ordering of the second element isn't relevant to my application that's why I've not included it in the comparator. So I'm OK with it being in any order, but the elements are not even being inserted.

Comment: @user308485 "I'm OK with it being in any order" means you are trying to do a partial ordering, but you can't do that with `std::set`. Set must have a strict weak ordering, i.e. every single element must be ordered with relation to every other element.

Comment: Yeah, it would appear your real problem was that you assumed the `compare`  parameter on the set is just for the ordering and the compiler would use some other magic to decide whether items are identical -- while in reality, it would just use `compare`  as well to determine whether they are identical...